# I would like to add dropdown list for Product tab i am used

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angularjs-scope

I would like to add dropdown list for Product tab. (Angular with bootstrap 3)

HTML:

```
<div class="animsition animated" ng-controller="websiteTabsCtrl">
    <tabset class="jdEMainBoxInRow">
                    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
                      <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
                    </tab>
                </tabset>
</div>
```

here is my code:

```
angular.module('website', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('website').controller('websiteTabsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'HOME', content:'home.php' },
    { title:'ABOUT', content:'about.php' },
    { title:'PRODUCT', content:'product.php' },
    { title:'CONTACT', content:'contact.php'}
  ];
});
```

like bellow

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find a suggestion implementation you can use.

Define your controller as:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'HOME', content:'home.html' },
    { title:'ABOUT', content:'about.html' },
    { title:'PRODUCT', content:'product.html' },
    { title:'CONTACT', content:'contact.html'}
  ];

  $scope.products = [
    { name: 'Product 1' },
    { name: 'Product 2' },
    { name: 'Product 3' }
  ];

});
```

And in `index.html` you can have:

```
<uib-tabset active="active">

    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs">

      <uib-tab-heading>

        <div ng-if="tab.title == 'PRODUCT'" uib-dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
          <div uib-dropdown-toggle>
            {{tab.title}} <span class="caret"></span>
          </div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="product in products" role="menuitem"><a href='#'>{{product.name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="tab.title !== 'PRODUCT'">
          <div>
            {{tab.title}}
          </div>
        </div>

      </uib-tab-heading>

      <div ng-if="tab.title !== 'PRODUCT'" ng-include="tab.content"></div>

    </uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

See working [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NSVTY11ORNyxLTqEFgmM?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the Ans and sorry, i was forgot to add html code (i am use Bootstrap 3). if you can give me Ans according to html and code. please thanks ones again.☺

Comment: Instead of `heading="{{tab.title}}"` (your code) you should use `<uib-tab-heading>` (suggested code) so as to differentiate tab headings, according to requirements (dropdownlist in product, simple heading in other cases. This is a possible valid solution I can suggest.

Comment: dropdown also is page load in your code page is not load from dropdown menu. like other main menu

Comment: Check here: https://plnkr.co/edit/aIlStHPyGinKSsMgoisq?p=preview Downgraded version of ui-bootstrap and removed all uib prefixes.

Comment: No my dear not work inner page of Product (Product 1, 2, 3 is not open line home, about) i cant see product 1, product 2, product 3 (there is just a come dropdown but not linked page.)

Comment: You mean you can't see pages for products? All you have to do is put in `<a>` tag the correct value. Besides, question was about showing dropdown list in tab heading.

Comment: Yes, how can i show i can't see inner product pages.

Comment: this is your code inner product list but there is no link page
`$scope.products = [
    { name: 'Product 1'  },
    { name: 'Product 2' },
    { name: 'Product 3'}
  ];`
like: `title:'HOME', content:'home.php'`

Comment: Please accept this answer (as it provided a solution to what you have asked) and post another question for what you should do in order to show product pages. (I have provided a hint earlier, you can use `<a>` tag accordingly).

Comment: i accept this answer but can you please give me an Example of which i asked now, i am not expert in Anguler that's why i am just simple designer so please and also my english is bed & this site will not accept similer Qus.

Comment: I'll try to find some time to provide with an example. Please tell me if you are using ui-router for routing or something else.

Comment: if you have any other way please provide.. or try to update your code i think you can do... thanks for help me.